# What correct annotation for this situation. JPA. Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I would create table, which contains objects. Objects should displayed like columns in table. (+ public, - private)

```
   +Company
    -int companyId
    -String companyName
    -Set<Department> listOfDepartments = new HashSet<Department>();

    +Department
    -int departmentId
    -String departmentName
    -Set<Worker> listOfWorkers = new HashSet<Worker>();

    +Worker
    -int workerId
    -String workerName
```

My unsuccessful attempt:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Company")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name="Company")
public class Company {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @XmlAttribute (name="id")
    @Column (name="idCompany")
    private int idCompany;

    @XmlElement(name="companyName")
    @Column (name="companyName")
    private String companyName;

    @XmlElement (name = "YYY")
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<Department> listOfDepartments = new HashSet<Department>();

@XmlRootElement(name="Department")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Embeddable
@Table(name="Department")
public class Department {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @XmlAttribute(name="idDepartment")
    @Column (name="idDepartment")
    private int idDepartment;

    @XmlElement(name="departmentName")
    @Column (name="deparmentName")
    private String departmentName;

    @XmlElement (name = "XXX")
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<Worker> listOfWorkers = new HashSet<Worker>();

@XmlRootElement(name="Worker")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Embeddable
@Table(name="Worker")
public class Worker {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @XmlAttribute(name="idWorker")
    @Column (name = "idWorker")
    private int idWorker;

    @XmlElement(name="workerName")
    @Column (name = "workerName")
    private String workerName;
```

Advise the correct annotation for this situation. I will appreciate.

```
UPDATE:
companyId|companyName|deptId|deptName|workerId|workerNam|
1|'Lala'|1|'Logical'|1|'Jason'|
1|'Lala'|1|'Logical'|2|'Bason'|
1|'Lala'|2|'Chemical'|1|'Cason'|
1|'Lala'|2|'Chemical'|2|'Dason'|
```

Comment: what do you mean by "displayed like columns in table"?

Comment: Can you update your question with your current result ? It may help people to help you :)

Comment: i mean that all entity(columns) should be shown by sql request "select * from company"

Comment: @EldarNezametdinov If I understand, you want to have only one table in your database ? Why ? In general, it's not a good practice... Do you have some specific constraints ?

Comment: @Nizil, i haven't practiced JPA before. Yes, i know that it's not normal form. You can create tables for each entity. I need working version (join, inheritance, embeddable) doesn't matter.
I can not do it by any method, for the three entity.

Comment: The `Embeddable`annotation seems out of place. Anyway, you should be more specific about which concrete issue you are having(compilation/runtime error, messages, logs)

Comment: and instead `ElementCollection` I would use `OneToMany`

Comment: @SJuan76 could you write example as a reply of this topic ? it will take a couple of minutes. i'm new one. it takes a lot of time for me (about hour - for one try) only hierarchy of annotations

Comment: -1: There are dozens of things that could be wrong (classpath, configuration, etc) and you are not taking the time to even specify what is the issue at hand... Get JPA working with one entity, and after that then try with relationships. And if you need help, clarify what is the issue that you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is some constraint that you want to save all object(entities) in one table in your case company(but the best practice is a normal data base design you should consider company department and workers in separate tables) you have redundancy in data and your table data seems like this...

```
1 comp1 1 dep1 1 worker1

1 comp1 1 dep1 2 worker2

1 comp1 2 dep2 3 worker3
```

then correct jpa annotation is:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Table(name="company")
public class Company{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @XmlAttribute(name="idComapny")
    @Column (name="idCompany")
    private int idcompany;

    @XmlElement(name="companyName")
    @Column (name="companyName")
    private String companyName;

   **@Embedded**
   private Department department;

   **@Embedded**
   private Worker worker;//can be removed and put in Department but result is the same
......
```

and put annotation **@Embeddable** on top of Department Entity and Worker Entity.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Department")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
@Embeddable
@Table(name="Department")
public class Department {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @XmlAttribute(name="idDepartment")
    @Column (name="idDepartment")
    private int idDepartment;

    @XmlElement(name="departmentName")
    @Column (name="deparmentName")
    private String departmentName;
```